# Better way to display Java

Tags: java

this is my 2nd class, the display it gives me is "null", is there a solution to my problem? How am I able to display my date of birth by calling the method?

```java
class studentInfo {
    
    private String format;
    
    public String date() {
        LocalDate dob=LocalDate.of(1996, 9, 8);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("8 September,1996");
        format=dob.format(formatter);
        return format;
    }
    
    public void displayInfo() {
        System.out.println("Date of Birth:"+format);
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println("Date of Birth:" + date());`

Comment: Or: `date(); System.out.println("Date of Birth:" + format);`

Comment: Class names should NOT start with a lower case character. Follow the conventions used by the JDK.

Comment: I recommend reading a tutorial on constructors, e.g. [this one by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

Comment: Hello and welcome. The problem is you most probably don't call date before displayInfo. I would call date from the construtor, and make it  private, if you are only using it from displayinfo.

Comment: How will you do that? Sorry new to Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call date() method first as this method is setting the value of the instance variable format, so when you call displayInfo(), you could see the set value.

Also updated the Pattern.

Here is the modified code:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

class StudentInfo {
    private String format;

    public String date() {
        LocalDate dob = LocalDate.of(1996, 9, 8);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        format = dob.format(formatter);
        return format;
    }

    public void displayInfo() {
        System.out.println("Date of Birth:" + format);
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StudentInfo studentInfo = new StudentInfo();
        studentInfo.date();
        studentInfo.displayInfo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Geezzz, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't call the method date().

Updated code :

```
class studentInfo {

    public String date() {
        LocalDate dob = LocalDate.of(1996, 9, 8);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM,YYYY", Locale.US);
        String format = dob.format(formatter);
        return format;
    }

    public void displayInfo() {
        System.out.println("Date of Birth:" + date());
    }

}

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        studentInfo info = new StudentInfo();
        info.displayInfo();
    }

}
```

Output :

```
Date of Birth:08 Sep,1996
```